# Definition of "step-point" as it relates to debugging/embedded

Tags: debugging, embedded, code-coverage, trace, iar

I was reading through an IAR description of using [CoreSight Trace Techniques](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aj2tS7vbCa9ywQyF6qrP-hwfTIR2b34y), and came across an example for generating "Statistics of Code Coverage".

They reference "**step point**" several times. A site-search for "step point" within the IAR site generates only the above link.

We can easily define ***instructions*** and ***lines of code***, so what is *exactly* is a ***step-point***, or better yet, a ***step-point level*** as referenced in the link above?

Comment: Please note, the link above is the cached version of the page, since IAR's isn't working at the moment

Comment: Using links prevents the long term value of a question and answer at stack overflow.  Cutting and pasting the relevant information into the questions and answers is preferred, that way the information is wholly contained within stack overflow and the question/answer is preserved for others to learn from.

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks for the insight. I think in this case, given that the term in question is not niche-specific, the link merely serves to provide an example of its existence, and contains no supporting context other than what is stated by "as it relates to debugging/embedded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step points appear to be how IAR describes executable statements.  For example, looking [here](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/005832/arm/doc/infocenter/tutor_debugging.ENU.html) and searching for step point shows how to walk through code one statement at a time.

Step point levels are likely branches taken or not taken.

A quick code example:

```
  //next two step points are at the same step point level.  There's no branch,
  //they will both always execute
  unsigned char qwerty=5;
  if(timer == 0x15)
  {
    Foo(5);  // another step point, a different step point level than above
  }
  else
  {
    // the next two step points are at the same step point level, as depending on 
    // the branch will either hit both or neither.
    unsigned char temp=5;
    Foo(temp);
  }
```

Comment: Ahh, so the definition of step-point is dependent upon the method/mode of debugging. I see. So stepping through execution via "Step over" defines step-points at the function level, but stepping through execution via "Next statement" or "Step Into" defines step-points at the statement level. Gotcha